# Use "callback" or "handler" to name a closure in swift?

Tags: swift, naming-conventions

I am working on naming convention document at the moment. Some of our developers prefer to use "callback" to name a func's closure property. Some of them prefer "handler".

Which one is suggested by most developers or official Apple docs?

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation? Without an official source, this will be up to popular opinion.

Comment: "continuation" :troll-face:

Comment: another idea is to us prefixes to indicated the event that the handler is associated with, on-, before- or after- onUserSelection, afterDataRead, beforeExit, for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forget that some people also just call it `completion`  and Apple actually uses `completionHandler` such as [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423621-reversegeocodelocation) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask).  Anyways I don't really think it matters what you call it.  We all know what it is no matter how you name it.  Just use completionHandler and point to the Apple docs if someone complains about it.